# CoreLocation see if requestAlwaysAuthorization() triggered popup

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

In my onboarding flow I'm first using requestWhenInUseAuthorization, here the user has 3 options:

1. Allow while in use
2. Allow once
3. Don't allow

In the callback didChangeAuthorization status however, there is no difference in the "Allow while in use" and "Allow once" options, both appear as "authorizedWhenInUse".

The real problem occurs in my next screen, where I'm asking for requestAlwaysAuthorization. If the user selected "Allow once", no popup will show asking if the user wants to

a. Change to always allow
b. Keep while in use

From here, my user is stuck in the onboarding flow.

My question and TL;DR: Is there a way to know the difference between user press "Allow once" and "Allow while in use", or is there a way to see if the alert view is being presented to the user?

Comment: You can't detect this but you don't need to know this actually. Regular you need to know user give you access for his location or not. All other things iOS make do it for you.

Comment: I do need to know, because my user will get to an onboarding screen where we will ask for "AlwaysAuthorization". If the user pressed allow once, he won't be prompted, and therefor will be stuck. While users that pressed "Allow while using" will have no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but working. After requestAlwaysAuthorization()

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState.rawValue == 0 {
    // No location permission popup appeared
    }   
}
```